# How to create buttons/shorcuts dynamically in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create an application where the user can enter shortcuts to files. I know how to create buttons in code at compile time but I have no idea how to create dynamic buttons where the name and the click event are going to be dynamic.

How hard would it be to create something like the image below? Is that even possible in C#/WPF/XAML?

What would be the logic?

FYI - I don't need help with saving the buttons objects, for this I will be using JSON.

[image]

Comment: "How hard would it be to create something like the image below?" relatively simple. "Is that even possible in C#/WPF/XAML?" of course. "What would be the logic?" ItemsControl bound to ObservableCollection

Comment: And use a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an `ItemsControl` to show what you want, this could be an approach:

```
<ItemsControl 
       ItemsSource="{Binding YourListOfLinkObject}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>                  
                  <Button Content="{Binding WhateverYouWantToShow}"
                          Command="{Binding YourCommand} " 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding YourFileName}"/>                  
          </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>   
</ItemsControl>
```

You should create a new (if it's not already created) class with the name of the file, the content you want to show in the button and your command. And when initializing the view, create a list of "Link" object.

The command will be the same for all of them, just declare it in a generic way to open the file you put in the `CommandParameter`

---

Now that I know you are using MVVM I will try to expand my answer focus on that.

You need a class that I will call `FileLink`. `FileLink` will have, at least, 3 properties:

- public string WhateverYouWantToShow - This will be the content of your button
- public ICommand YourCommand - This will have a `DelegateCommand<string>` that will be the one who "does" things. This command will be the same for every item you create. You just need one because you will use the parameter to execute/open one file or another.
- public string YourFileName - This will be the string you need to execute your command method. I guess it will be a path or a file name.

Now that we have this class created, when initializing the third view, the one with the buttons, you will have an `ObservableCollection`property, what I called `YourListOfLinkObject`, of `FileLink`objects. There you will have to add as many `FileLink` objects as you got from the database and they will be displayed.

If you need to change the way they are shown you just need to modify the `DataTemplate`.

If there's something I failed to explain again or you want me to go further just let me know :)

Comment: Would you mind going through your code? Am I correct to say that the `YourListOfLinkObject` will be bound to an ObservableCollection, the `WhateverYouWantToShow` to a property for the buttons name, the `YourCommand` to click event property? I'm not sure what the `YourFileName` will be bound to. Can you please elaborate a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: `WhateverYouWantToShow` is what will be shown to the user instead of "Button1" or "Button2". With `YourFileName` I meant whatever you need to use to open/execute what you want your button to do. If you need a path to open the file, `YourFileName` will be a string like "C:\XXXX\XXXX". I'm sorry i didn't explain myself :P

Comment: @ Juan Carlos Rodriguez-  I won't lie to you, I'm still a little confused about the binding and logic in my ViewModel for `YourCommand` and `YourFileName`.

Comment: Check it out  :D

Comment: @ Juan Carlos Rodriguez - Your updated answer is very well explained but you touched on something I'm not familiar with, that is `DelegateCommand<string>` I will try to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179022/discussion-between-juan-carlos-rodriguez-and-fs-tigre).

Comment: FYI - I ended up using `RelayCommand` since I'm using framework `MVVM Light` and I believe `DelegateCommand<string>` is for the Prism framework. Here is the link that shows my complete solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096427/pass-parameter-for-dynamic-buttons-mvvm-light/52096648?noredirect=1#comment91143807_52096648

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and simple. You add controls to your container and add container to main form. Click event is simply defined in code (which actually you know at dev time - probably you should instead use user controls).
Below is some partial code, doing a similar thing in a real world Silverlight application from years ago to give the idea:

```
 ...
 sp.Children.Add(p);

        foreach (var slot in group)
        {
            var color = colors[(int)slot.State];
            var name = String.Format("W{0}", slot.When.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"));

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
            {
                Name = name,
                Width = rectWidth,
                Height = rectWidth,
                Margin = new Thickness(rectMargin),
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(slot.State == Availability.Booked ? Colors.White : Colors.Black),
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color),
                RadiusX = 2,
                RadiusY = 2,
                Cursor = (slot.State == Availability.Booked ? Cursors.Arrow : Cursors.Hand)
            };
            if (slot.State != Availability.Booked)
            {
                rect.Effect = new DropShadowEffect(); //myDropShadowEffect,
            }
            if (slot.State != Availability.Booked)
            {
                rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rect_MouseLeftButtonDown);
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(rect, slot.When.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy dddd hh:mm tt"));
            }
            sp.Children.Add(rect);
        }
        b.Child = sp;
        contentStackPanel.Children.Add(b);
    }
```

Comment: IMHO this is too much code when you can simply code it in XAML without any code behind.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez, If you like coding XMLish why not? I prefer in code and actually dropped using XAML since they killed Silverlight - learnt not to trust MS based technologies the hard way. And I had all this at runtime only.

Comment: Because any change in the UI will become harder... also, if you have worked with `StackPanels` you probably know that they don't manage their space correctly in some scenarios

Comment: I fail to see how this code will handle items which are added or deleted from any index in list dynamically

Comment: @Ash, as I said this is partial code. You can provide a full blown one instead of down voting others.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez, you don't need to use only StackPanel. That is a sample as you might have guessed. It doesn't make UI change harder but easier.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, there shoudn't be other UI code expect for ItemsControl, shown in another answer. You can study it fully instead of complaining about XAML or accusing me of downvoting

Comment: @Ash, you can do it with ItemsControl and I can do it dynamically in code, ok?