# Pass Parameter for Dynamic Buttons - MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

The following code successfully creates two buttons dynamically, what I can not figure out is how to make the buttons open a different files when clicked.

What am I missing?

#### XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonName}" 
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding FilePath}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

#### ViewModel:

```
namespace DynamicControlsMvvmLight.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<ButtonModel> _dataButtons = new ObservableCollection<ButtonModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<ButtonModel> DataButtons { get { return _dataButtons; } }

        private ICommand _buttonCommand;
        public ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get {
                if (_buttonCommand == null) {
                    _buttonCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CommandExecute, CanCommandExecute);
                }
                return _buttonCommand;
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ButtonModel data1 = new ButtonModel("Button 1", ButtonCommand, "c:/Folder/File1.PDF");
            ButtonModel data2 = new ButtonModel("Button 2", ButtonCommand, "c:/Folder/File2.PDF");
            DataButtons.Add(data1);
            DataButtons.Add(data2);
        }

        private void CommandExecute(object FilePath)
        {
            ButtonModel button = FilePath as ButtonModel;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(button.FilePath);
        }

        private bool CanCommandExecute(object FilePath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CanCommandExecute Method...");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Model:

```
namespace DynamicControlsMvvmLight.Model
{
    public class ButtonModel
    {
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }
        public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public ButtonModel(string buttonName, ICommand buttonCommand, string filePath)
        {
            ButtonName = buttonName;
            ButtonCommand = buttonCommand;
            FilePath = filePath;
        }
    }
}
```

#### ERROR

I get the following error when I click any of the buttons.
[image]

Comment: inspect `object FilePath`. it should be `string`. cast it to string to get filepath

Comment: Got it, changed `ButtonModel button = FilePath as ButtonModel;` to `string button = FilePath as String;` and it did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you dont understand the nature of the problem. Look at my answer

Comment: @ThierryV - Thank you for showing and pointing out the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelayCommand` expects to receive `CommandParameter` which is a `string` in this case.

The code must look like:

```
        public ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_buttonCommand == null)
                {
                    _buttonCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(CommandExecute, CanCommandExecute);
                }
                return _buttonCommand;
            }
        }
```

and

```
        private void CommandExecute(string filePath)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
        }
```

Comment: @ Thierry V - Thanks a lot for your help. Quick question, at this point the code works fine and does what I need but I'm wondering if the structure of my code looks fine, in other words, am I using `ICommand` and `RelayCommand` correctly?

Comment: In my opinion, I think it was fine.